# How to extract values from column and update result in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    IdDate int,
    FullDate varchar(255)
);

insert into MyTable (IdDate,FullDate)
VALUES (0, 'Nº1 (26) - Friday 4, January 2014'),
       (0,'Nº2 (64) - Monday 10, February 2015')
```

I wanna extract from FullDate something like this:

```
1 2014 01 04
2 2015 02 10

1st number is extracted from Nº1
2nd number is extracted from Year
3rd number is extracted from Month (convert January to 01)
4th number is extracted from day (if day < 10, add 0 at the beginning: 01,02... )
```

And update the new value extracted in first column called IdDate

My final result should be like:

```
IdDate        FullDate
120140104     Nº1 (26) - Friday 4, January 2014
220150210     Nº2 (64) - Monday 10, February 2015
```

Comment: The root of your problem is that you are storing dates as strings. Datatypes exists for a reason, don't do this to yourself. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Yes i know. But i dont have another choice. When I get the new IdDate, I will remove the column FullDate

Comment: Can you share some actual sample data? Meaning a create table script followed by a couple of insert statements. Oh goodness....I think your column actually has all that extra garbage in there???

Comment: Febrary???  Oh no.

Comment: Shared table script

Comment: Do you really have misspelled months in your data? Or is that just a typo while posting?

Comment: @Greenspark forget a letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If open to a helper Table-Valued Function:

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (IdDate int,FullDate varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (0,'Nº1 (26) - Friday 4, January 2014')
,(0,'Nº2 (64) - Monday 10, February 2015')

Update A
   set IdDate = substring(Pos1,3,10)
              + try_convert(varchar(10),try_convert(date,Pos6+' '+Pos5+' '+Pos7),112)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row](FullDate,' ') B
```

**Returns**

```
IDDate      FullDate
120140104   Nº1 (26) - Friday 4, January 2014
220150210   Nº2 (64) - Monday 10, February 2015
```

**If it Helps with the Visualization, the TVF Returns**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
)
```

**Or Without the Function**

```
Update A
   set IdDate = substring(Pos1,3,10)
              + try_convert(varchar(10),try_convert(date,Pos6+' '+Pos5+' '+Pos7),112)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(FullDate,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

> **EDIT**

This is an expanded version of Shawn's **cleaner** solution

```
Update @YourTable 
   set IdDate = substring(left(FullDate,charindex(' ',FullDate)-1),3,25)
               +try_convert(varchar(10),try_convert(date,replace(substring(FullDate, charindex(',', FullDate) - 2, 100), ',', '')),112)


Select * from @YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when i run your code show me IdDate = Null. Isnt like your screenshot

Comment: @RaulEscalona try_convert() will return a NULL if the conversion fails.  Misspelled date?  Extra spaces?  Bogus Date like June 31  ?

Comment: I just copy and paste your first code. And show Null

Comment: @RaulEscalona  here is a dbFiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b23683e56877631837debfd81bbf2442

Comment: It works correctly in your link, but in my database it does not. I am using SQL SERVER Express 2017

Comment: @RaulEscalona See the EDIT in my answer.  I just expanded Shawn's solution

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help, but Null is still showing

Answer (score 2):

This will extract a date value. It just looks for the comma, backs up a few characters and grabs the date, strips the comma and treats it as a military date.

```
select convert(date,  
   replace(substring(FullDate, charindex(',', FullDate) - 2, 100), ',', ''), 106)
```

Use `format()` or date style 112 to get the output the way you need. The first character is apparently just `substring(FullDate, 3, 1)` so just append that to the front.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to wrestle this without using a function like John posted (which is what I would do) you can dig in and start a nightmarish path of string functions. The challenge is that t-sql is not great at string manipulation.

This seems to work on the sample data you provided. Note that if you have data that can't be converted to a date this will fail.

```
update MyTable
set IdDate = substring(FullDate, 3, CHARINDEX(' ', FullDate) - 3)
    + Right(FullDate, 4)
    + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datepart(month, convert(date, replace(substring(substring(FullDate, charindex('-', FullDate) + 2, len(FullDate)), charindex(' ', substring(FullDate, charindex('-', FullDate) + 2, len(FullDate))) + 1, len(FullDate)), ',', '')))), 2)
    + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), datepart(day, convert(date, replace(substring(substring(FullDate, charindex('-', FullDate) + 2, len(FullDate)), charindex(' ', substring(FullDate, charindex('-', FullDate) + 2, len(FullDate))) + 1, len(FullDate)), ',', '')))), 2)

select * from MyTable
```

Then go ask the person who decided to store data like this why they did it? This is not how to handle data at all.

Comment: Error converting a string of characters in the date and / hour.
my column FullDate is varchar(255)

Comment: You must have some garbage data. It works fine using your sample data and table.

Comment: When I get the new IdDate, I will remove the column FullDate

Comment: Oy!!! You are going to go from one terrible design to another. Stop the insanity!!! This is two pieces of information. A number and a date. Cramming them together is still violating 1NF. Make this into two columns or you will continue to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
1st number is extracted from Nº1
2nd number is extracted from Year
3rd number is extracted from Month (convert January to 01)
4th number is extracted from day (if day < 10, add 0 at the beginning: 01,02... )
```

Use [SQL Server's string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to do the following

1. Get the characters between `Nº` and the first blank space that follows it.
2. Get the last 4 characters
3. Use a CASE expression to generate a month number based on what month name is LIKE the string
4. Get the 2 characters before the comma, and replace any blank characters in that with a `0`.

And concatenate those 4 values together.

Comment: But how can i do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 (also added to answer).  You have asked a broad question and I have given you a broad strategy.  Use this link to do some research and make an attempt to solve the problem.   If you get stuck on any one of these techniques, make that a new question, so that you can focus your question on one specific technique.

Comment: I disagree Tab. The OP doesn't know what to do. They have provided functional ddl and sample data. It is clear what they expect as output. This data is such a complete trainwreck that it isn't easy to unravel this mess.